# Adding children to custom elements

Tags: javascript, css

I've created my own custom element extending `HTLMElement` and attached a shadow root and style like this:

```
class Popover extends HTMLElement {
    mode = "vertical"

    constructor(){
        super();

        let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}),
            style = shadow.appendChild(document.createElement("style"))
    ...
```

This is intended to be a popover menu for example. I want to add children to it and keep their style.
Let's imagine my style is something like this

```
.Circle {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

I create a `div` element and apply the style like this

```
let circle = document.createElement("div");
circle.className = "Circle";
document.body.appendChild(circle);
```

and my red circle is correctly displayed.
I want now to add that circle to my custom element rather than `document.body` and here problems come.
If I append it to my custom element like this, it won't show (although it's actually there in DOM inspector):

```
let p = new Popover();
p.appendChild(circle);
document.body.append(p);
```

My circle is not displayed. However if I look in DOM inspector, the circle div is actually there and .Circle properties are also applied.

If I then try to append it to `shadowRoot` instead to the custom element itself, the div is the displayed but all properties form `.Circle` class are gone (not applied).

```
let p = new Popover();
p.shadowRoot.appendChild(circle);
document.body.append(p);
```

So, how can I add content to my custom element and preserve document classes?

Comment: So where is your styling for the Circle class actually placed? If you want to style elements within the shadow DOM, then you need to inject your styling _into_ the shadow DOM as well. (I see you are creating a style element and appending it to the shadow DOM, but it is unclear if you actually put the stylesheet rule into that as well.)

Comment: Yeah that's nthe point... I need a solution that allows me to keep styles even if they are declared at domument level and not at shadow level

Comment: So to put it another way – you want shadow DOM, only you don’t want it to work like shadow DOM is actually supposed to? Not sure what sense exactly that is supposed to make, but either way, it’s not a pick-and-choose. Don’t know if there is any other solution than to loop over all stylesheets embedded into the document, and explicitly insert them into the shadow DOM again.

Comment: Or even attach the child to custom element (not to shadow) and have it displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I learned that:

1. Attaching shadow dom will replace any element children (they won't be displayed) so children must be then attached to shadow root instead
2. Shadow DOM won't use document level styles

So I decided to override the `appendChild` method of my custom element so that the element being attached will be attached to `shadowRoot` and its computed style is grabbed and copied to it (the following method is part of my custom element `class`:

```
appendChild(element){
    if (!element instanceof HTMLElement)
        throw new TypeError("Expected HTMLElement");

    document.body.appendChild(element); // ensure that style is rendered
    let style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
    element.style.cssText = style.cssText;

    return this.shadowRoot.appendChild(element);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Due to an [old bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137687) in Firefox, I had to change my code like this:

```
appendChild(element){
    if (!element instanceof HTMLElement)
        throw new TypeError("Expected HTMLElement");

    document.body.appendChild(element); // ensure that style is rendered
    element.style.cssText = this.getComputedStyleCssText(element);

    return this.shadowRoot.appendChild(element);
}

getComputedStyleCssText(element){
    var cssObject = window.getComputedStyle(element),
        prop,
        cssText,
        cssAccumulator = [];

    if(cssObject.cssText != ""){
        return cssObject.cssText;
    }

    for(prop in cssObject){
        if(typeof cssObject[prop] == "string"){
            cssAccumulator.push(prop + " : " + cssObject[prop]);
        }
    }
    return cssAccumulator.join("; ");
}
```

credits: https://gist.github.com/johnkpaul/1754808

**EDIT 2:**
Even better recursively:

```
appendChild(element){
    if (!element instanceof HTMLElement)
        throw new TypeError("Expected HTMLElement");

    document.body.appendChild(element); // ensure that style is rendered
    
    // do it recursively
    let setStyle = element => {
        element.style.cssText = this.getComputedStyleCssText(element);
        Array.from(element.children).forEach(child => setStyle(child));
    }
    setStyle(element);

    return this.shadowRoot.appendChild(element);
}

getComputedStyleCssText(element){
    var cssObject = window.getComputedStyle(element),
        prop,
        cssText,
        cssAccumulator = [];

    if(cssObject.cssText != ""){
        return cssObject.cssText;
    }

    for(prop in cssObject){
        if(typeof cssObject[prop] == "string"){
            cssAccumulator.push(prop + " : " + cssObject[prop]);
        }
    }
    return cssAccumulator.join("; ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN, the cleanest approach is to use slots:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/slot

On GitHub, they added this example with a custom paragraph:

https://github.com/mdn/web-components-examples/tree/main/simple-template

Note that, when you use a `slot` element in the shadow root, the normal DOM element nested in your custom element is still able to use CSS classes define in the DOM.